# Deadlock при сортировке результата выборки

Tags: mysql, innodb, транзакции, deadlock

Имеется запрос, выполняемый параллельно множеством потоков в собственных транзакциях:

```
SELECT `account_id` FROM `accounts`
WHERE `request_mts` < :request_mts
ORDER BY `request_mts` ASC
LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
```

...где "account_id" - первичный ключ, а ":request_mts" - число миллисекунд.

Этот запрос часто приводит к дедлокам:

> Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
>
> QMYSQL3: Unable to store statement results

Проблема, как удалось выяснить, связана с сортировкой выборки. Если сортировку из запроса убрать, то дедлоки более не возникают:

```
SELECT `account_id` FROM `accounts`
WHERE `request_mts` < :request_mts
LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE
```

Есть ли способ сохранить сортировку, но при этом избежать и дедлоков?

**Дополнено**

После выполнения выборки (если был найден подходящий `account_id`) идёт запрос на обновление колонки `request_mts` в той же транзакции, что и выборка. После этого транзакция закрывается.

```
UPDATE `accounts` SET `request_mts` = :request_mts
WHERE `account_id` = :account_id
```

Comment: А процессы потом этот request_mts меняют ? или как они умудряются не зацикливаться в обработке одной и той же записи ? Вообще надо подумать, нельзя ли исключить необходимость блокировок, например раздавая записи на обработку потокам по остатку от деления mts на количество потоков или каким нибудь одним потоком - диспетчером

Comment: Это при каком уровне изоляции? попробуйте опуститься до `READ COMMITTED`. Ещё может помочь наличие покрывающего индекса.

Comment: @Mike, дополнил ответ. Следом идёт обычный `update`, который и обновляет `request_mts`, если на предыдущем шаге нужный `account_id` был обнаружен. Можно немного подробнее об этом: "раздавая записи на обработку потокам по остатку от деления mts на количество потоков"?

Comment: @Akina, да, установлен `READ COMMITTED`. Что такое "покрывающий индекс"?

Comment: @alexis031182 если задать условие `request_mts < :request_mts and request_mts % кол-во-потоков = номер-потока` то два потока физически не смогут получить одну и ту же запись, потому что у них номера разные. при этом записи по потокам будут распределены боле менее равномерно (если конечно у вас кол-во миллисекунд не кратно постоянно одному и тому же числу)

Comment: @Mike, интересная идея, спасибо.

Comment: @alexis031182 Покрывающим называется индекс, включающий в себя все поля таблицы, задействованные в запросе (и, возможно, другие поля - не влияет). В этом случае обращение к таблице вообще не нужно, сервер использует сам индекс как компактную таблицу. В Вашем случае покрывающим (и очень даже подходящим для этого запроса) будет, например, (request_mts,account_id).

Comment: @Akina, попробовал, но к сожалению не помогло.